# pyrocms i want to display keywords separated in the loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms, pyro

this code display applied keywords to the childrens pages

```
{{ pages:children id="1" order-dir="desc" limit="15"  }}
{{ custom_fields }}
{{keywords}}
{{ /custom_fields }}
{{ /pages:children }}
```

I have 3 keywords applid to some page so i want to display keywords separated in the loop and not as a string with all keywords in one loop but to be aloop with number of keywords related something like

```
{{ pages:children id="1" order-dir="desc" limit="15"  }}
{{ custom_fields }}
{{loop}}
{{keywords}}
{{/loop}}
{{ /custom_fields }}
{{ /pages:children }}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display keywords separately as well - just use opening and closing tags;

```
{{ if keywords }}
    <div class="keywords">
        {{ keywords }}
          <span><a href="{{ url:site }}blog/tagged/{{ keyword }}">{{ keyword }}</a></span>
        {{ /keywords }}
    </div>
{{ endif }}
```

The above is taken from the [Blog module](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/modules/blog) single post view - look in /system/cms/modules/blog/views/view.php for the source.  The [Keyword field type docs](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/field-types/keywords) also have a couple of similar examples.